# Conflicts in ArcMap editing with multiple users

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

There are multiple users of ArcMap using their own versions for uploading edits to our Master database. We are not live editing, these edits are reconciled and posted each day, sometimes twice in one day to the parent version.

There is debate within my team of why we are consistently getting conflicts in ArcMap between users - more often than not the conflict version is a later edit version than the pre-reconciled edit therefore some right click on the conflict and click replace with conflict version.

Others right click on the conflict and select Mark as visited.

We are wondering whether both of these options are correct and that we are just destined to always have conflicts or just the one option is correct and would prevent many of the conflicts we are having with others and ourselves?

We are also receiving conflicts with ourselves from previous day edits - could this just be user error when reconciling and posting or could it be influenced by the time the servers are set to as we have been told the servers are set to UTC time as opposed to NZ standard time.

Conflicts from others that are no where near our area also happens often and results from marking these conflicts as visited are producing weird copy's of previously edited polygons.

Comment: Edit the data directly or work in such a way as to reduce the chance of conflicts. A conflict will arise where two (or more) users make an edit to the same feature, both being legitimate, the latter users in a checkout situation will not see the earlier edits so the other users' edits are overwritten - this is bad. If you can't edit the data directly make sure no two users are in the same area *or else*.

Comment: Thank you. Yes we have found that edits have sometimes been lost when multiple users have been editing the same area.

Comment: When you say you are not live editing does this mean you are using checkin/checkout replicas? If so can you limit the spatial extent of each replica to just the areas the editor will be working on? When reconciling we found the selecting the option to "reconcile by attribute" instead of the default "by feature" greatly reduced the number of conflicts. As far as the correct method of resolving conflicts, the feature with the correct geometry and attributes should be the one that is chosen as current.

Comment: Yes at the end of each day we reconcile and post from our different versions and they are uploaded to the default version (Parent version) over night. I will bring up the "reconcile by attribute" for discussion today anything to limit the number of conflicts.                                                Currently when we get conflicts, usually first thing every morning - we follow an interactive conflict resolution and go through each conflict and select either "replace object with conflict version" or "mark as visited". Wondering if we should stop selecting the "mark as visited" altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue while working on the utility network database. It happens when two user modify the same feature attribute/geometry in two different ways. Try reconciling the version only after refreshing parent database .